# Get N number of CGPoints around a circle on UIView

Tags: ios, swift, geometry

I got a center `CGPoint` and radius `Float`, I need to get N number of points surrounding the circle, for example in below image how to get the 12 points corresponding red dots.

[image]

This is my incomplete function:

```
func getCirclePoints(centerPoint point: CGPoint, and radius: CGFloat, n: Int) [CGPoint] {
    let result: [CGPoint] = stride(from: 0.0, to: 360.0, by: CGFloat(360 / n)).map {
        let bearing = $0 * .pi / 180
        // NO IDEA WHERE TO MOVE FURTHER
    }
    return result
}

getCirclePoints(centerPoint: CGPoint(x: 160, y: 240), radius: 120.0, n: 12)
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaking, I think there is a missing part in your question, what's the distance between each point? what I mean is that I could distribute 12 points on a smaller circle as well as a larger one, what's the criteria of distributing the points?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You were almost there!

```
func getCirclePoints(centerPoint point: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, n: Int)->[CGPoint] {
    let result: [CGPoint] = stride(from: 0.0, to: 360.0, by: Double(360 / n)).map {
        let bearing = CGFloat($0) * .pi / 180
        let x = point.x + radius * cos(bearing)
        let y = point.y + radius * sin(bearing)
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
    return result
}
let points = getCirclePoints(centerPoint: CGPoint(x: 160, y: 240), radius: 120.0, n: 12)
```

I didn't think `and` was very clear as an argument name so I've removed this.

Answer (score 2):

Use radians instead of degrees. They are needed inside trigonometric functions

```
func getCirclePoints(centerPoint point: CGPoint, and radius: CGFloat, n: Int) -> [CGPoint] {
    return Array(repeating: 0, count: n).enumerated().map { offset, element in
        let cgFloatIndex = CGFloat(offset)
        let radiansStep = CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(2.0) / CGFloat(n)
        let radians = radiansStep * cgFloatIndex
        let x = cos(radians) * radius + point.x
        let y = sin(radians) * radius + point.y
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
}
func getCirclePoints1(centerPoint point: CGPoint, and radius: CGFloat, n: Int) -> [CGPoint] {
    var resultPoints: [CGPoint] = []
    let radianStep = CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(2.0) / CGFloat(n)
    for radians in stride(from: CGFloat(0.0), to: CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(2.0), by: radianStep) {
        let x = cos(radians) * radius + point.x
        let y = sin(radians) * radius + point.y
        resultPoints.append(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
    }
    return resultPoints
}
func getCirclePoints2(centerPoint point: CGPoint, and radius: CGFloat, n: Int) -> [CGPoint] {
    let radianStep = CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(2.0) / CGFloat(n)
    return stride(from: CGFloat(0.0), to: CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(2.0), by: radianStep).map { element in
        let cgFloatIndex = CGFloat(element)
        let radiansStep = CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(2.0) / CGFloat(n)
        let radians = radiansStep * cgFloatIndex
        let x = cos(radians) * radius + point.x
        let y = sin(radians) * radius + point.y
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
}

getCirclePoints(centerPoint: CGPoint(x: 160, y: 240), and: 120.0, n: 12)
```

Comment: You don't have to put `CGFloat(...)` everywhere. You don't have to wrap literals, for example. `CGFloat.pi * 2` would do. You also have constants `radianStep` and `radiansStep` which have the same value.

Comment: Is it anyway to start from pi/2 position instead of 0 without making a rotation @Vyacheslav ?

Comment: @QuangLuu I didn't understand your question.  You can set any initial angle you want. But don't forget about shifting by moving matrix

Answer (score 2):

For having a draw reference

```
import UIKit

let numOfItems = 10

class customView : UIView {

    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        for i in 0...numOfItems
        {

            let angle   = 360/CGFloat(numOfItems)  * CGFloat(i) * .pi / 180

            let rad = self.bounds.size.width/2 - 10

            let x =  bounds.midX + cos(angle) * rad

            let y =  bounds.midY + sin(angle) * rad

            let circlePath = UIBezierPath(
                arcCenter: CGPoint(x:x,y:y),
                radius:10,
                startAngle:0,
                endAngle:360,
                clockwise: true)

            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

            shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
            shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
            layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        }

    }

}
```

[image]